# VBA Macro - check particular boxes

Tags: excel, vba

good morning!

I'm developing a small project and I came across with this Macro world aka "Macro VBA Scripting" that I never heard of before.

Is something pretty basic I guess, but I still struggle with it.

What I did so far?
A lot of google searches.

and I did my own method:

```
Sub Clickall()
With Selection
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range("Check Box 2").Select
.Value = xlOn
.LinkedCell = ""
.Display3DShading = False
End With
End Sub
```

But this one only checks 1 box at a time. And it fails a lot of times, without any reason.

Then I found this:

```
Public Function Check(filePath As String, sheetName As String)
Dim xlWorkbook As Workbook
Dim xlWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim xlRange As Range
Set xlWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(filePath, UpdateLinks:=False)
Set xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName)
For Each chkBox In xlWorksheet.CheckBoxes
chkBox.Value = xlOn
Next chkBox
xlWorkbook.Save
xlWorkbook.Close
End Function
```

But in this case, is checking all the boxes at the same time and I want to check only particular boxes.

[image: List of check boxes]

So, when I receive that excel file. Checkboxes 1,2,3,4 will already be checked.
My job is to check, checkboxes number 5,6,7,8,9, and leave uncheck the checkboxes number 10 and 11.

Did someone have any idea how to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Are there always 11 boxes? Then a counter can help that stops after 5 circles

Comment: Hi, @Capt.Krusty, yes, always 11 boxes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plese, test the next code. Not returning anything, it is enough to be a `Sub`:

```
Sub CheckCB(filePath As String, sheetName As String)
 Dim xlWorkbook As Workbook, xlWorksheet As Worksheet, xlRange As Range, i As Long
 Set xlWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(filePath, UpdateLinks:=False)
 Set xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName)
 For i = 1 To xlWorksheet.CheckBoxes.count
    Select Case i
        Case 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
              xlWorksheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box " & i).value = True
    End Select
 Next i
 xlWorkbook.Close , True
End Sub
```

Comment: What does "Select Case" do?

Comment: @Capt.Krusty It does exactly what its name suggests... When i =5, or 6, or the enumeration there, it executes the following code line.

Comment: Ah cool, so a "loop with holes" is now possible for me, thanks! Upvote! :)

Comment: @Capt.Krusty The solution I tried supplying offer the possibility to easily adapt the code if more check boxes would be used and even discontinuous numbers would be used. Something like 2, 4, 6, 7, 8 ... When you cannot iterate directly, without a lot of `If` - `Enf If` conditions.

Comment: @Capt.Krusty What is interesting, is the fact that I can see above the up vote, but nothing has been counted in my notoriety wallet... Even refreshing the page.

Comment: Thats the best thing to do: give a snippet and let us learn!
Sorry that the points are not appearing. Hope my answer gets upvoted too for trying ;)

Comment: @Capt.Krusty This is not a problem for me. I have enough notoriety. I just do not understand what happens. It may be a delay or something. I don't really care about that. Just now I received 15 points from accepting the answer I posted to another question and these ones not. Even more strange...

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Public Function Check(filePath As String, sheetName As String)
Dim xlWorkbook As Workbook
Dim xlWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim xlRange As Range
Dim i As Integer
Set xlWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(filePath, UpdateLinks:=False)
Set xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName)

For i = 5 To 9
   xlWorksheet.OLEObjects("Checkbox" & i).Object.Value = True 'Give name as String as your checkboxes are named
Next i

xlWorkbook.Save
xlWorkbook.Close

End Function
```

Comment: Didn't your code raise an error on the line `a = "Checkbox" & i`? In your case, you should declare it as `String`... But a shorter variant would be to skip this variable and use the concatenation directly instead of `a`.

Comment: Amazing work @Capt.Krusty , this small piece of code is a true engineering work. Thank you a lot for your time and effort. 
You're big man. Thank so much!!

Answer (score 1):

you can operate with checkboxes using an array of indexes or names `.CheckBoxes(Array(...))`

```
Sub SetCheckBoxes()
    ' set all the CheckBoxes to False
    ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Value = False
    
    ' option one: indexes of the checkboxes = checkboxes numbers
    ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(Array(5, 6, 7, 8, 9)).Value = True
    
    ' option two: indexes of the checkboxes <> checkboxes numbers
    arr = Array(5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)    'make array with the checkboxes names
        arr(i) = "Check Box " & arr(i)
    Next
    ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(arr).Value = True    'apply
End Sub
```